# tor is not working with python on windows

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-install

i have installed tor and torrequest package for python. while working with torrequest package from python i faced the problem that

```
OSError: 'tor' isn't available on your system. Maybe it's not in your PATH?
```

here is what i enter the python code

```
with TorRequest() as tr:
resp=tr.get('http://ipecho.net/plain')
print(resp.text)
```

and it raised the error 
i installed tor browser 
what should i do ?
do i need some other package to work with it

Answer (score 1):

After skimming what I believe is [the TorRequests source code](https://github.com/erdiaker/torrequest), it looks like you either need to

1. properly point TorRequests at Tor Browser's ControlPort and SocksPort, or
2. add tor.exe to your path so TorRequests can launch Tor itself.

Option 1 is easier.

The example in the README tells you how to specify the socks and control port to use.

Tor Browser opens a SocksPort on 9150 by default and a ControlPort on 9151 by default.

(To the best of my knowledge, TorRequests is not created by anyone associated with the Tor Project)